# How to dynamically get the array value list based on the 'id' in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
**User.vue**

<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="list in lists" :key="list.id">{{ list.val }} {{ list.kk }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { datalist } from "./datalist";
export default {
  name: "User",
  data() {
    return {
      lists: datalist,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

```css
**datalist.js**

export const datalist = [
  { id: 1, val: "11", kk: "potter" },
  { id: 2, val: "22", kk: "james" },
  { id: 3, val: "55", kk: "limda" },
  { id: 4, val: "77", kk: "stepen" }
];
```

```html
**HelloWorld.vue**

<template>
  <div>
    <b>Vuejs dynamic routing</b>
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
      <b>{{ item.id }}.</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'UserWithID', params: { id: item.id } }">
        {{ item.kk }}
      </router-link>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />

    <b> {{ $route.params.id }}</b>
    <User />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import User from "./User.vue";
import { datalist } from "./datalist";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {
    User,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: datalist,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I am working on dynamic routing, Where onclick of each array value, I am getting the "id" dynamically.(like 1,2,3,4,5......)

Now I want to display the array values. specific to the id only. like...

if i click on **id:1** then i need to get only the specific array values which is linked with the **id:1** only. Similarry for 2,3,4....

At present problem is, If click on **"array id:2"** or any id valuess.. then i am getting the whole array values list.

```
1
```

11 potter
22 james
55 limda
77 stepen

Complete working code:- https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-fast-sokui?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: If you want to find specific data in an array, you can use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) like `datalist.find(user => user.id === someId)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find needed user info by `$route.params.id` in `User.vue`.
Example `User.vue`:

```
<div v-for="(item, key) in user" :key="key">
  {{ item }}
</div>
...
computed: {
  user: function () {
    return this.lists.find((item) => item.id === this.$route.params.id);
  },
}
```

Demo
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-moon-lv80s)

Comment: Thanks. Now I am getting the specific array values based on id. But what if i want to show the array value called -->"val" only in the specific array value by id.

Comment: If you want to show only one property `val`, you don't need to use `v-for`, just use `{{user.val}}` instead of `<div v-for="(item, key) in user" ...`